# Beam of light at the end of "Battle of Corrin"

Tags: dune, brian-herbert

At the end of the last battle described in *Battle of Corrin* when people are destroying last version of Omnius there is 'beam of light' fired by machines.

Is this explained in other chapters or elsewhere in the book series?

Comment: That was Frank Herbert's soul permanently abandoning the franchise in disgust.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The canon quote you're referring to is:

> Soldiers shouted, and the Cultists made warding signs, screaming to
>   vanquish the unexpected demon. **The liquid-silver flowmetal spire
>   twisted and reshaped, billowing out at the end like an inverted
>   umbrella, a parabolic dish of some sort.**
>
> **A transmitter!**
>
> With a groan like a dying sea beast, the Central Spire convulsed and
>   then vomited a flash of light, shooting a signal upward through the
>   atmosphere like a scream out into space, where it would dissipate
>   across the parsecs. Then the Central Spire collapsed, lost its
>   integrity, and splattered into puddles across the broad, rubble-strewn
>   plaza.

An earlier chapter makes it crystal clear that **Omnius is intending to transmit a copy of himself into the heavens** in the hopes that a future civilisation will (either accidentally or deliberately) download a copy of him into a form capable of unfolding his intelligence, thus starting the machine war all over again.

> Corrin was about to fall, because of them.
>
> Before the two faulty copies struck him down, Omnius Prime had
>   developed a perfectly acceptable means of escape, a way to allow the
>   core copy of his evermind to survive. **He had the ability to code all
>   the information that comprised his entity into a giant datapacket. As
>   a mere signal, not a gelcircuitry construction, it would be able to
>   pass through the scrambler net.** “Omnius” would drift across the galaxy
>   until he found some receiver, anything that could download him.
>   Anything he could inhabit.

Although it's not explicitly stated, one way of preventing this from occurring would be to prevent future human colonies from possessing computers powerful enough for this to be a threat (nudge, nudge, wink, [wink](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Butlerian_Jihad))

For the record, this strategy is [wildly successful](http://dune.wikia.com/wiki/Enemy/XD) (warning : spoilers)

Comment: Due to the fact english isn't my native language I faced difficulties in describing my question. Your answear was bull's eye. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Remember in the Butlerian Jihad, when Omnius sent out the many self replicating robots throughout the galaxy to several different planets? Perhaps he was sending his copy of himself to update the everminds on those planets.

Comment: Do you have any canon information to add mate?